# Manage external websites through SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, cms

I have many HTML & ASPX sites hosted on IIS. I want centralized solution to manage those sites so I have selected SharePoint 2013 as platform.

I do have ASP.NET application which handles all the things by which i can update any site like If i wan to "*update any page*", "*change or update the css or image or js*", "*Change or update the content on master page*", etc.

Than after I am using FTP to update those changes in live site which is hosted under my IIS (Simply copy entire site structure & update them to IIS site's location).

**Is there any SharePoint 2013 site template available to manage external site's content?**

Comment: meaning you want to manage your external asp.net site using sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Yes that exactly i want